# Meaning of the phrasal verb "clean up" in context

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrasal-verbs

It was in the ninth episode of ninth season of Friends. Here is the transcription:

> [Scene: Ross and Rachel's apartment. Ross is in the living room
> covering Emma. Rachel enters wearing a sexy dress.]
>
> ROSS: Wow! (pause) Wow, You look . . . uh . . .It's just, ah . . .
> That dress . . . uh . . .
>
> RACHEL: Well, I hope the ends of these sentences are good.
>
> ROSS: Well, well, they're good. It's been a while since I've seen you
> like this. You, you **clean up** good.

Comment: I'm more accustomed to hearing "clean up nice," but "good" is clearly a variation of the same phrase: https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/clean+up+nicely

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's a joke, meaning that you look nice after you clean yourself up... wash your face, take a bath, etc. It's an insult because it suggests that you are usually dirty, but it's meant as a joke.

Comment: Brits sometimes say "you scrub up nicely" to someone who has made an effort to appear groomed. It is not an insult.